# How can I trigger redirect with custom modal Vue login component + axios?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I can get a 200 status response and show '/home' view in the consoles preview section

but how can I trigger redirect in axios following 200 response?

Currently the custom modal view does not close but when I refresh the page I am logged in.

```
   methods: {
        login() {
            axios.post('/login', this.$data)
                 .then(response => console.log(response)); // response.status = 200
                 .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/login-with-custom-modal-vue-component-axios

Got an answer here 
LC 1
SO 0

:p